# One word for someone who hates everyone and everything? (Not just humankind)

Tags: single-word-requests

I know the word **misanthrope**, but it is used for the general hatred towards humankind. I'm looking for a word, if there is one, which can be used to describe hatred towards everything like humans, objects, existence, systems, etc.

Comment: A dead person walking?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ***nihilist***:

***[Nihilism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nihilist)***:

> total and absolute destructiveness, especially toward the world at large and including oneself:
>
> - the power-mad nihilism that marked Hitler's last years.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Nihilism suggests more to the essence of pointless, meaningless than to the hatred. Please correct me if I'm wrong.